# How do i use a defined table name for PDO statement?

Tags: php

I have in one of my config files all the table definitions, eg.

```
define('tbl_admin', 'site_admin');
```

I'm using PDO statement to get some values from the table, but i'm unable to call up the 'site_admin' table.

My code as follows:

```
      $db=new database();
      $pdo_db_connx=$db->PDO_database();          
      $smt=$pdo_db_connx->prepare("select id from tbl_admin where  admin=:username");
      $smt->bindParam(":username",$username);
```

Any advise please?

Comment: Interpolate a variable, or concatenate your constant into the query. PDO doesn't transpose literals with PHP constants by itself.

Comment: You can use `"select id from " . tbl_admin . " where admin = :username"` or `sprintf("select id from %s where admin = :username", tbl_admin);`

Answer (score -1):

When you do:

```
$smt=$pdo_db_connx->prepare("select id from tbl_admin where  admin=:username");
```

`tbl_admin` is considered a table name `tbl_admin`, and not a constant.

The simpliest way is to concatenate parts of query with a constant:

```
$smt=$pdo_db_connx->prepare("select id from " . tbl_admin . " where  admin=:username");
```

Here, `tbl_admin` will be treated as constant and it's value will be used.

Comment: This was my first attempt before posting the question.Strangely, it didnt work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I realise the definition doesn't work for this problem. The alternative is to assign table name to a variable, such as :

```
$tbl_admin="site_admin";
```

and the query will be:

```
$smt=$pdo_db_connx->prepare("select id from $tbl_admin where  admin=:username");
```

This works.